# Use S3 cloud storage, like Amazon or another, to store data, instead of OpenText Archive Center

Tags: opentext

The question is about storing data in cloud (not Amazon but it has S3 in title), which has simple API with post request for saving and get request for fetching data/files.

The problem is that I also have 5Tb of files which are storing using OpenText Archive Center. So is there any solution to switch storage provider of OT Content Server to something cloudy?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I believe you can configure the Archive Centre side to access S3 style storage.

Comment: thank you for your answer! it seems that cloud solution that my company has buyed has possibility to be connected to servers with Content Server as a network folder. So, as I know, Content Server can store files simply in file structure, I think that it will be ok to connect this network folder

Comment: and do you know wich version of archive center supports s3?

Comment: I don't exactly but you should find out easily on the Knowledge Centre.